# All Tic Tac Toe Board Possibilities - Stack Overflow - Java Recursion General Trees

Tags: java, recursion, tree, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to generate all possible moves in the game tic tac toe with recursion and trees in java.

I am using General Trees and recursion which I find to be tough. However, the first generation in the tree should have 1 spot filled, then the next generation has 2 spots filled, then the next generation has 3 spots filled, then the next generation has 4 spots filled, etc.

My aim is to create a Node:

```
       #
      / 
     #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
    / / / / / / / / /
(should be filled) #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
```

Each child node has 9 siblings.
Each sibling has 1/9 possible placements.
An 'X' or 'O' is alternated and placed in each new generation of children (in 1 out of those 9 spots).
By the last generation, the tree should be filled with X's and O's.

Trouble: My insertLayer method is recursively called infinitely. It gets stuck somewhere between the 6-8 when I input a counter to keep track of how it is growing.

Comment: I did I printed the method out 5 times and traced it out, I tried to `return root;` after each recursive call and it made zero difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition is always true:

```
if (gameBoard[i][j] != 'X' || gameBoard[i][j] != 'O')
```

so you’ll recurse forever.

Change `||` to `&&`:

```
if (gameBoard[i][j] != 'X' && gameBoard[i][j] != 'O')
```

or better, because it’s clearer and simpler:

```
if (gameBoard[i][j] != ' ')
```

Note: This may not be your only bug, but it’s the most obvious and severe one I noticed.

Comment: It worked! However, now I'm only creating 9 nodes. Is that a degenerate tree of 9 children, or is it 1 layer of 9 siblings?

Comment: To fix your next problem, after recursing, erase the cell you just filled, ie `gameBoard[k][l] = ' ';`

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “siblings”. If you want to generate all possible boards, just do that. Note that some boards are impossible final states of games, eg both players making lines of 3. Also, many boards are rotations/reflections of each other, including reversing players, so the number of *truly* distinct boards is quite small.

Comment: That makes it loop infinitely between nodes 7, 8, 9. I think the children nodes (each layer) need to fill up the board with an extra placement, but the sibling nodes try different possibilities of that extra placement.

Comment: Should be 9! (9factorial) boards. Once I have over 300,000 possible boards, then I will cut off branches to confine to rules.

Comment: not sure how to generate all possible boards. kind of stuck

Comment: Recursion may not be the best approach. If the homework doesn’t say you must use recursion then try an iterative algorithm.

Comment: Since all full boards have 5 X and 4 O, you only need to place the 4 O - the Xs are implied. I would fill with X, then iterate through all combinations of placing 4 O in a 4-deep nested loop, restoring X after each write, make a copy of the board in the deepest loop, and it to a list, then prune the list of symmetrical dupes and impossibles. Note that some games finish before all 9 are used - the shortest game uses only 5 cells. You may need to cater for these too.

Comment: @dan btw it’s not 9!, because there are not 9 choices, there are only 2 choices, so it’s 2^8 ie 256 for a full board (not 2^9 because flipping X and O isn’t really a new board).

Comment: There are 9 choices to fill the board with an (just 1) X or O, then 8 choices to fill the board with an X or O, then 7, and so on... It can't be 2 choices my friend. There are 9 possible spots on the board. Therefore 9! permutations

Comment: @DanielG You're right, there are 9 choices for first move, 8 for second move, and so on, **but** that is the math for making *moves*. Multiple move combinations produce the same board layout. E.g. if first 3 moves are 1-2-3, or 3-2-1, the result is X-O-X either way, so the total number of board layouts is not 9!

Comment: @dan you’re wrong there. Each cell has 2 choices: X or O. That is a fact. There are 9 cells. That too is a fact. So, there are 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 permutations, or 512. There’s no getting around that. (Of those, by inspection know half are the exact opposite - ie X and O swapped. That leaves 256 total actual permutations). If you use a 9! algorithm you’ll find only those unique 512, but many times over. Of the 256, only those with 5 X and 4 O will be valid. That will be very few indeed.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying now, you're correct. However I was hoping to do the pruning of the tree (symmetry and applying the win rules) later on. Im sure the pruning will confuse me, as I can't get around the infinite looping of my recursion in the first place

Comment: @Bohemian Math-wise, it's selecting the 5 cells for the 5 X's, i.e. unordered combinations, so `9! / (5! * 4!)` = `362880 / (120 * 24)` = **126**. Eliminating mirrored and rotated duplicates, you get much less. Math-wise it's a bit more complex, because some of those "full" boards are invalid, since 3-in-a-row also happens before the board is full, ending the game.

Comment: Wild! So how do I implement this? I get an infinite recursion :(

Comment: How about looping from 0 to 512 and using the lower 9 bits to paint the cells (1=X and 0=O). You can use `char c = (i & (1 << n)) > 0 ? 'X' : 'O';` where i is the loop var and n is the cell number, to get the character. Alternatively, you could just store the board as an `int` and *render* it using such code.